# Can the reputation points gained by accepting an answer be modified?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, reputation

The majority of questions on H.SE do not have accepted answers. Accepting an answer gives +2 to someone's reputation. If this bonus was larger, we would probably see more questions having accepted answers. Is it possible with SE to modify the bonus amount for accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I don't think it's a problem for lots of questions, even most, on this site to not have an "accepted" answer. Even though question acceptance is officially only meant to purely indicate that the question asker alone was satisfied by the answer, it does make a question feel like it has been completed, that it's been correctly answered, and no more answers are needed. This will be especially true to new members of our site who don't know that the tick mark only means the asker liked it and nothing more. (The site doesn't communicate this particularly well.) On this site there is almost always something more to say, more insights to glean from the scriptures, or alternative ways to explain them. So I think it's fine for questions to remain without an accepted answer.

Comment: Should we just get rid of the Accepted button entirely, then? If it doesn't really serve a purpose on this site ...

Comment: «So I think it's fine for questions to remain without an accepted answer.» maybe because only 4% of questions asked in this community don't have an answer? In other words, if we were speoking of over 50% (maybe 33% even) the take would be different...

Answer (score 0):

**Keep 'Accepted Answer' practice** It is possible, and most likely that the practice of "accepting answers" gives great *incentive* to Answerers for providing a most worthy, well thought-out, finely researched Answer. The fact that a worthy Answer will be recognized would give--and does give--impetus to users on BH to dig deeper into the commentaries and exegetical resources, which benefits all the users (readers of the answers).

Even if a user may mistakenly think more answer are unneeded on that particular Question, he (she) will give due diligence on other questions and desire to produce meaningful and scholarly answers that are worthy of acceptance by meeting the need of the Asker.

For more insight on this idea of continuing to answer Questions already accepted, see Question # 3367!